# Formatting columns of text in vim (alignment)

Tags: vim, macvim

Is there any short cut to quick edit this with vim beside recording action, then apply to all lines?

From:

```
French Polynesia  French Polynesian
Gambia The Gambian
Georgia Georgian
Ghana Ghanaian
Grenada Grenadian
Guam  Guamanian
```

To:

```
French Polynesia  French Polynesian
Gambia            The Gambian
Georgia           Georgian
Ghana             Ghanaian
Grenada           Grenadian
Guam              Guamanian
```

Comment: Built-in? No. Anyway, there is no clear structure to the input text so there is very little room for automatisation/optimisation, here. If that was TSV, then it would probably be *doable* but there is no `<Tab>` to separate `Gambia` from `The Gambian` so your outlook is pretty bad.

Comment: @romainl, I can delete the The from The Cambian, if there is any short cut. (Then add it back)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can replace the spaces with hyphens like below (from your example, it's
hard to give a method for this initial step that I'd be sure would work with
other variations that you might have in your data):

```
French-Polynesia  French-Polynesian
Gambia The-Gambian
Georgia Georgian
Ghana Ghanaian
Grenada Grenadian
Guam  Guamanian
```

Then you can run `%!column -t` to get this:

```
French-Polynesia  French-Polynesian
Gambia            The-Gambian
Georgia           Georgian
Ghana             Ghanaian
Grenada           Grenadian
Guam              Guamanian
```

Then do `%s/-/ /g` to get to this:

```
French Polynesia  French Polynesian
Gambia            The Gambian
Georgia           Georgian
Ghana             Ghanaian
Grenada           Grenadian
Guam              Guamanian
```